# Cant ping my PC on LAN until user is log in directly. destination host unreachable

Tags: linux, ping, local-area-network

It shows this when pinging from other devices in the local network

```
From 192.168.0.191 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
```

However once I log in my PC (192.168.0.191) I can ping it from other devices in the Network and even start ssh connection to it. how can I make it to be accessible to the local network without any logged in user?

PC has Manjaro OS (Archlinux)

Comment: Is network actually up before the user logs in, or is it brought up by user login?

Comment: my network does not depend on that particular pc, it is up continuously

Comment: Network on that pc. E.g. does the OS enable the network interface before a user logs in.